# Is it possible to determine the currently active scheduler plugin in YARN with the command line?

Tags: bash, hadoop, sh, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'd like a command that will tell me whether the currently running instance of the ResourceManager is running the fair or the capacity scheduler (or some other custom plugin).

I know it is possible to get this programmatically, since it's displayed in the ResourceManager's native GUI, but I'm wondering if possibly one of the `yarn` subcommands (or even a shell command) can provide it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so I've come up with something, and it's ... in a word ... horrid:

```
wget -S -O - http://<rm-host>:<rm-web-port> |& grep Scheduler | egrep -v "href|Metrics|Type" | tr -d '[[:blank:]]'
```

Surely there must be a better way...